# Using Views from other Class Library in my Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Let's say I have an Class Lib called `Controllers` and other Class lib called `Views`

Inside `Views` there are my `.cshtml` files and in Controllers there are mine `.cs`

How can I "convince" my controllers to use `Views` from that project / class lib called `Views`?

Project structure:

```
|
|
|-- MyViews
        |
        |-- MyTestView.cshtml
        |-- Shared
                |
                |-- shared.cshtml
|-- Controllers
|-- AppRunner (Program Main, Startup.cs)
```

I've tried

```
// {2} is area, {1} is controller,{0} is the action    

services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear(); 
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/MyViews/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/MyViews/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
}
```

or

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear(); 
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("~/MyViews/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("~/MyViews/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
}
```

or

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
{
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Clear(); 
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/../MyViews/{1}/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
    o.ViewLocationFormats.Add("/../MyViews/Shared/{0}" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension);
}
```

but all of them return error that couldnt find cshtml file in those locations

Comment: And what is preventing you from just putting the views within the same project and assembly ?

Comment: Is the MyViews project directly under the solution?  Because you need a full path, starting  from AppRunner.  How about `~/../MyViews...` ?

Comment: @AliEzzatOdeh nothing, but separation makes it easier to control whole project when it grows.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ``MyViews`` is at the same level as ``AppRunner``. I'll try ``~/../``

Answer (score 0):

Views that live in the main web app will always override views from a class library. But views can certainly be used from a different class library than the controllers.

In order for the views in your views class library to be discovered, your views class library must use sdk Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor, and it must have a direct dependency on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc

Without that it will not see the views in your class library.

And the main web app must reference the class library.

You don't need that view location expander logic.

UPDATE:

Your views project csproj should look something like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="path-to-yourview-models-project.csproj" />
      --maybe other project refs here
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note that Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor is not a package dependency.

Also the views in your class library need the same folder structure conventions as if they were in the main web app.

```
 Views
   Home
      .cshtml files
   Shared
      .cshtml files
   _ViewImports.cshtml
```

you can put them in folders corresponding to the controller name without "Controller" suffix, or you can put them all in shared

Comment: MyAppRunner:

  ``<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Controllers\Controllers.csproj" /> // Because I need to registry an assembly
    <ProjectReference Include="..\MyViews\MyViews.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>``

Comment: Controller:
  
  ``<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.1" />
   </ItemGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Views\Views.csproj" />
   </ItemGroup>``

Comment: MyViews:
   
  ``<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="2.1.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor" Version="2.1.1" />
  </ItemGroup>``

Comment: But still ``InvalidOperationException: The view 'Login' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Home/Login.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Login.cshtml``